# How to access files outside the document root

Tags: php, webserver, lamp

In a LAMP Webserver PDF help files are stored outside the document root in a given path `/var/myFiles/help/`. The path is set to read access which was done by the admin. To read and show them on a web page I use this code

```
define(PDF_PATH,"/var/myFiles/help/");

$file = PDF_PATH.'help.pdf';
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$name.'"');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
```

But finally I get a PDF file NOT FOUND error on the webpage.
What do I do wrong ? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT :

For better understanding I update the question. This is the given path structure

```
/var
   /www
       /html

   /myFiles
       /help
           /help.pdf
```

How to access help.pdf and show it on a webpage ?

EDIT 2: I update the path in the define method to match the above example

Comment: @Anant . Both define variants do not succeed. DocumentRoot = /usr/local/apache/htdocs

Comment: @Ben check the two links i given

Comment: @Anant -  I ckecked, still no success. See my EDIT above.

Comment: @Ben `define(PDF_PATH,"/var/myFiles/help/");`

Comment: @Anat - I try this path (and update it above) but the browser still say : Failed to load PDF document. Is this a problem with the header() declaration or maybe a problem of insufficiant access rights ?

Answer (score 0):

I answer the quesion myself

The answer of Anant is correct. I forgot to add @readfile($name) after the header() declaration in the php file. See question above.